# Scala - what is case class private

Tags: scala

I am analyzing my existing project, I found some this like this(conceptually):

```
case class AA private(id: String) {}

case class BB(id: String) {}
```

After I created those two classes to observe the difference. I analysed their java source by using java decompiler. I did not find any different.

> What is the need of private there.
>
> What is the importance of that.

Comment: `AA` has private constructor

Comment: I observed, AA, BB have public constructor. AA$, BB$ have private constructor.  I am using JD-GUI decompiler.

Comment: Some of the Scala metadata is not directly observable from the decompiled code. You'll probably have to parse the ScalaSig annotation on the classes themselves to spot the differences.

Comment: JD-GUI is a decompiler for Java, it doesn't know anything about Scala. You can't trust anything it says.

Answer (score 5):

A case class is a class which gets a Companion object automatically defined with a few helper functions. One of these is an apply method which essentially allows to skip out the 'new' keyword when defining a class. The private keyword in your example makes the constuction of a new AA using the 'new' keyword private. Eg:

```
case class A private(id: Int)
case class B(id: Int)
A(1) //Using public method
B(1) //Using public method
new A(1) // Using PRIVATE method
new B(1) // Using public method
```

Answer (score 3):

You can understand this better using Scala REPL

```
scala> case class A private(a: String)
defined class A

scala> new A("")
<console>:14: error: constructor A in class A cannot be accessed in object $iw
       new A("")
       ^

scala> A("")
res3: A = A()
```

*Notice that instantiation of the `A` cannot be done using `new` keyword. `private` helps restrict the instantiation of A using `new`(makes it private)*

Comment: Sorry, I did not get, any have, you will create an instance.

Comment: @Sun notice that instantiation of the A cannot be done using new keyword. private helps restrict the instantiation of A using new(makes it private)

Comment: @Sun .. private stops you from creating object using `new` keyword

Comment: So, Can I create only one instance of `A` by making private, am I right, If you call `A()` again, it will give new one or old one.

Comment: @Sun it will give you a new one.